# Unlocking HR User Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to unlock the HR user on oracle 12c. I have done the following steps.
I have inserted

```
PDBORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
  )
```

)

in tnsname.ora. I then ran lsnrctl reload in the command prompt. Next,

1. I log in to oracle:

   ```
   sqlplus sys as sysdba
   ```
2. `ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = pdborcl;`
3. `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE open`
4. `ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT unlock;`
5. `conn hr/hr @pdborcl;`

At step 5, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE
```

I have double checked and I am sure that con_name (pdborcl) is right and that the name of the service is right in tnsname.ora. Why am I unable to connect?

Comment: That message has nothing to do with locking.

Comment: yes, but I came to the error trying to unlock the HR user

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below commands to find out the issue.

1. `tnsping pdborcl`

   success: move to next step.
   Fail: there is no TNS entry for pdborcl. May be TNSnames.ora file is different    location other than you mentioned. it is depend on TNS_ADMIN variable
2. `lsnrctl status | grep pdborcl`

   it will check service pdborcl is registered with lsnrctl
   If it is failed, you need to register your DB with listener.
3. `alter session set container=pdborcl;`
   `select account_status from dba_users where username='HR';`

   This will show the account status of HR. It should be open.

Comment: When I run tnsping pdborcl success and I get: "Used parameter files: C:\app\jjh35\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\SAMPLE\sqlnet.ora TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name". My TNS_ADMIN is set to C:\app\jjh35\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\SAMPLE . The Sample folder contains the LISTENER, sqlnet, and tnsnames files. Is there an issue with my TNS_ADMIN variable?

Comment: Just just i observed, In step 5 there is space.

Comment: Just now i observed, In step 5 there is space between password and sid.   "conn hr/hr @pdborcl;". Could you please try without space. And make sure tnsnames.ora file in C:\app\jjh35\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\SAMPLE folder. and any update on command "lsnrctl status | grep pdborcl". And you mentioned "tnsping pdborcl" is success, but there is error in next line. it means there is no entry in tnsnames.ora file

Comment: I removed the space in step five and the result is the same. I moved the tnsnames.ora file to C:\app\jjh35\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN folder as it should be set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to the correct path. I made sure that my tnsnames.ora file has the pdborcl code as listed in my question.

Comment: When I run  'tnsping pdborcl', I still get the same error. Before the error message (TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name), it says "Used parameter file: C:\app\jjh35\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora". Should I also have the parameter file "C:\app\jjh35\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsname.ora"?